# http server files download counter without website

Tags: iis-7, log-files

I'm looking for a statistics tool on server side (IIS7) with following requirements:

- Displays file downloads via http (no websites to click on)
- Can set specific range to display results (download count)

Is there such thing? I don't need tons of statistics, just file download count.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a web log analyzer. Somthing like this might work.

http://www.weblogexpert.com/info/IISLogs.htm

Comment: has no date range selection :/

Comment: you can select the date range by selecting the logs in that range.

Comment: Yes, it does - you can choose the log files to analyse against.